# Unable to call external Bash program when exporting project as runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, bash

I have a java project that requires an external bash script to work. It works perfectly fine in Eclipse, but once I export it as a runnable jar, I get the following error: Cannot run program "src/script.sh": error=2, No such file or directory

I have tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("script.sh");
```

As well as

```
new ProcessBuilder("src/script.sh").start();
```

The Bash script takes in no input and does not return any output

Comment: arguments tu review for such issues. BTW poor program are full of system ("CLS"). What functionality stay behind?

Comment: If you don't know where you need to place the script in relation to how you run the jar, use absolute paths

Comment: @thatotherguy It worked but unfortunately I plan on distributing my app, so if I used an absolute path, only I would be able to run it on my local machine

Comment: If no path is specified, $PATH will be searched. If a relative path is specified, it will be relative to the current working directory (which is independent of the location of the jar).

Comment: When you run code in IDE, IDE has its own classpath definition.
But the classpath will be difference in runable jar file. 
I recommend you to define a absolute path of shell file or get path from java argrument.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is buried inside the jar file and doesn't exist as a standalone file, that's why Java can't "execute" it. You need to read it at runtime using the resources API, then save it to some (temporary?) directory, set its executable permission, and only then run it using ProcessBuilder or some such.